# Auto batch for all of the layers in my mxd

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, batch

I have a mxd file with more than 800 layers, and I want to convert all of these layers to KML files. I have tried to use the batch option in the "Layer to KML" tool, but I have to set there every layer manually, which is crazy.
Is there any way to auto-fill all of the layers in my mxd file into the batch table? There is any other way to convert multiple layers into a KML files? (One KML file for each layer).

Comment: Have you tried multiple selecting then dragging and dropping from the TOC into the batch grid?

Comment: Are you open to use a python script?

Answer (score 2):

You may use [Map to KML](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/map-to-kml.htm) (converts many layers in mxd to kmz):

> This tool converts a map document into a KML file containing a
>   translation of Esri geometries and symbology. This file is compressed
>   using ZIP compression, will have a .kmz extension, and can be read by
>   any KML client including ArcGIS Explorer, ArcGlobe, and Google Earth.

Answer (score 0):

Use a python script. Scripts can be executed in the [Python window](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/python-window.htm) in ArcMap. Code below will run Layer to KML for all layers in the MXD. For each layer a kmz file will be generated. If you want to specify any optionals parameters you can do so, see [Layer To KML](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/layer-to-kml.htm) for help.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Temp\KML' #Change path to where you want to store the KMZ files
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\Temp\Untitled.mxd') #Change to Point to your MXD

for lyr in  [x for x in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd) if x.isFeatureLayer]:
    arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(layer=lyr, out_kmz_file=lyr.name+'.kmz')
```